# Is there a library to map Dynamo Db Map<String ,AttributeValue> to an Object?

Tags: jackson, gson, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I am trying to use DynamoDb transaction library scan operation :

https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-transactions/blob/master/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/transactions/TransactionManagerDynamoDBFacade.java#L214

Scan operation return ScanResult which contains Map. Is there a better to map it to an object ?

There is an interface called ItemConvertor http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/ItemConverter.html , is there any concrete implementation for this ?

Comment: Have you looked at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBMapper.html?

Comment: It has a method- marshalIntoObjects and it is working for me. Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Used DynamoDbMapper's -  marshalIntoObjects(..)

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBMapper.html

Comment: marshalling has been deprecated, use `DynamoDBTypeConverter ` instead:  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBTypeConverted.html